# How to make the AlertDialog persist even after going to other Activity?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

Whenever any user opens my application after it has been logged out due to session expired. I Have two process running simultaneously, one, an intent to MainActivity form the Splashscreen and the second is the AlertDialog which is called in the BAseActivity. So Suppose my AlertDialog is currently visible on the Splashscreen and some process is going in background and when it finishes the intent takes the application to the MainActivity.

The problem is my AlertDialog is getting canceled. is there any way to persist the AlertDialog through all the Activity?

Answer (score 1):

It is the context problem ,because dialog is using the same activity context , If this dialog has to be on Top always, it can be done with `SYSTEM_ALERT_SERVICE` like

```
public void showCustomAlert(String text){

    final String alertText = text;

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            AlertDialog.Builder myDialogBox = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
            myDialogBox.setTitle("Alert");
            myDialogBox.setMessage(alertText);
            myDialogBox.setCancelable(false);
            myDialogBox.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){

                  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                         dialog.dismiss();
                  }

            });
            myDialogBox.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
                  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                         dialog.dismiss();
                  }
            });
            AlertDialog alertDialog = myDialogBox.create();
                  alertDialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
            alertDialog.show();
       }
    });
    }
```

Take care of `"android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"` permission. Hope this resolves your issue .

Answer (score 0):

No. You can only set a value, either in an Intent to MainActivity or as a value in SharedPreferences, to tell MainActivity to show that Dialog again.

Dialogs in Android are attached to an Activity. They display in that Activity's Window. Once that Window is destroyed (ie when that Activity finishes), or once the Window is put to the background, that Dialog won't show anymore.

Comment: What about using the DialogFragment?

Comment: What about it? It's still a Dialog.

Comment: The way to go is with a `DialogFragment`. A Dialog shown by other means (some are even deprecated) gets removed when the Activity loses focus, but a DialogFragment gets restored with the rest of the activities state.

Comment: @frozenkoi yes, but the OP wants to keep the same Dialog across Activities. A DialogFragment won't solve that.

Comment: @TheWanderer oh I didn't realize that. You're right, there's not such thing as app-wide dialog.

Comment: @JinsonPaul what? You can't make that show over a new Activity you start, if that's what you mean.