# Android standalone Alert Dialog

Tags: android, android-studio

The normal way to create an alert dialog is to attach it to the current activity, like in [How do I display an alert dialog on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115758/how-do-i-display-an-alert-dialog-on-android)

However, what I want to achieve is to create an alert dialog that is not attached to a particular activity. So that when the activity is destroyed (e.g. using finishAndRemoveTask), my dialog is still here.

Is there a way to achieve that? Also, I would like the area outside of the alert dialog to be unclickable, i.e. the user must click on the ok button of the dialog in order to navigate to other activities.

Comment: "Dialogs are supposed to attached to an activity's window using its context and stay alive inside its life-cycle"  -  So a simple answer you can't show same dialog when it's parent is destroyed. It will lead to crash and a [window leak exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850573/activity-has-leaked-window-that-was-originally-added)

Comment: What about the answer by Jinson Paul in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9751088/how-do-i-display-a-dialog-in-android-without-an-activity-context ?

Comment: Which answer are you talking about, I couldn't find it

Comment: Sorry, should be this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52711976/how-to-make-the-alertdialog-persist-even-after-going-to-other-activity/52713141

Comment: Using `SYSTEM_ALERT_SERVICE` - it might work but this approach will have have few problems. Like `TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT` ,   shows alert in complete android system no matter in which application user is. These windows are intended for system-level interaction with the user.  Using a system level permission only to show a dialog between two activities might be get approval from the play store, and also if not handled properly, user may exit the app using back press but dialog might still persist.

Comment: You should create a Dialog Themed Activity . You can manage Activity stack as per requirement